# best approach to map HTML XML to POJO

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to set up the mapping scheme for an html xml file, I'm really looking for advice.  I'm new to unmarshalling xml content. to me it looks as if I need a class for each section.  I'm hoping there is a better way.  My file looks like this. I'm just getting started trying to understand how to tackle this problem and my head is spinning :).  I'm looking at a class for HEAD, a class for HEADRTR, a class for FDE and a class for MM sections.  but this seems it will become awkward and cumbersome having many maps of lists. real world example of machinery generated status messages. ??? thank you for your suggestions. The parts needed are the contents of the HEAD section, the contents of the HEADRTR section and the contents of the FDE and MM sections.

```
A   008812111835040016XXXXXXXXXX
<RTR>
<HEAD>
<IDCMS pn="ABF31A6FNCL0004" vers="4.0"/>
<DA>2018/12/11 00:15:42</DA>
<ACD MSN="0160" tail="N504DN" type="A350-900"/>
<TID>C00000023</TID>
</HEAD>
<HEADRTR>
<FROM>ZSPD</FROM>
<TO>KLAX</TO>
<FNBR>DAL88     </FNBR>
</HEADRTR>
<ITD>
<CB>A</CB>
<FDE disp="n" dm="y">
<MC>3031H050</MC>
<MD>A-ICE // &gt; A-ICE SIDESLIP PROBE 2 HEATG</MD>
<DA>2018/12/11 00:12:42</DA>
<CDA>2018/12/11 00:14:17</CDA>
<FPH>8</FPH>
<LAB>1</LAB>
</FDE>
<MM fo="A" occ="5">
<MC>3413F7EV</MC>
<MD>PROBE-SSA,2(11FP2)</MD>
<DA>2018/12/11 00:08:43</DA>
<ATA>3413</ATA>
<FPH>8</FPH>
<FCL>1</FCL>
<PRIO>high</PRIO>
<STA>1</STA>
<SYS name="ADR2" bite_id="3" side="2"/>
</MM>
</ITD>
</RTR>
```

---

here is the start, the head class, wondering if you can tell me if I'm going down the right path. is this the/a correct way to do attributes and elements?

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "HEAD" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Head {

String pn;
String vers;
String da;
String msn;
String tail;
String type;
String tid;

public String getPn() {
    return pn;
}
public String getVers() {
    return vers;
}
public String getDa() {
    return da;
}
public String getMsn() {
    return msn;
}
public String getTail() {
    return tail;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public String getTid() {
    return tid;
}

@XmlAttribute(name="pn")
public void setPn(String pn) {
    this.pn = pn;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="vers")
public void setVers(String vers) {
    this.vers = vers;
}
@@XmlElement(name="da")
public void setDa(String da) {
    this.da = da;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="msn")
public void setMsn(String msn) {
    this.pn = pn;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="tail")
public void setTail(String tail) {
    this.tail = tail;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="type")
public void setPn(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
@XmlElement(name="tid")
public void setDa(String tid) {
    this.tid = tid;
}

}
```

Comment: Having a class for each element of the represented pojo is pretty standard. You'll want to create a jaxb unmarshaller in this case. Here is a good example: https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-jaxb-20

Comment: thanks I will try this out let you know.  appreciated!

Comment: Zack, thanks, wondering if you could tell me, am I doing this right? included the head class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite, your model is too flat for the represented structure.

```
<HEAD>
    <IDCMS pn="ABF31A6FNCL0004" vers="4.0"/>
    <DA>2018/12/11 00:15:42</DA>
    <ACD MSN="0160" tail="N504DN" type="A350-900"/>
    <TID>C00000023</TID>
</HEAD>
```

Each child element needs to define their own child elements and/or attributes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "HEAD")
public class Head { 
    @XmlElement(name = "IDCMS") private Idcms idcms;
    @XmlElement(name = "DA") private String da;
    @XmlElement(name = "ACD") private Acd acd;
    @XmlElement(name = "TID") private String tid;
    ... getters/setters
}

public class Idcms { 
    @XmlAttribute(name = "pn") private String pn;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "vers") private String vers;
    ... getters/setters
}

public class Acd {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "MSN") private String msn;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "tail") private String tail;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type") private String type;
    ... getters/setters
}
```

Comment: you saved me from much pain and agony, thank you Zack